# python path to script can take two forms

Tags: python, file, syntax

I have noticed, in python, that the path to a script can take 2 forms

```
filename.py
```

or

```
filename/__init__.py
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for will offer detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply, if you have a large filename.py containing many classes. you want to split them into separate files, and keep them under the same namespace. you can use the 2nd method.